# Used SelectedIndexChanged for combobox for autocompletion but its not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, selectedindexchanged

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="cmbNames" 
              runat="server"                 
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbNames_SelectedIndexChanged" 
              DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
              DataTextField="name" 
              DataValueField="id" 
              MaxLength="0" 
              style="display: inline;" 
              AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:ComboBox>
```

Used this datasource for for adding values to the combobox.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Tender_Module1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [name] ,[id]FROM [contract]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is code of combobox.

```
protected void cmbNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand("select name,street,town,dist from contract where name=@names", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@names", cmbNames.SelectedIndex.ToString());
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmds.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    street.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                    town.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                    dist.Text = dr[3].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the code is not working and autofill fails. Please help...

Comment: You do know that PostBack for an autocomplete list will be horribly slow? And probably just not work?

Comment: Actually I have no other option to implement the same. But Confused why this event is not firing

Comment: Is there an initial list so the user _can_ change the index?

Comment: no i used datasource for that

Comment: I thing the event is now triggered but code is not working i.e. data is not filing in textbox